# Symbolizing a file geodatabase layer using every attribute field?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, file-geodatabase, time

I'm trying to export an animation using ArcGIS 10.3.1. I have monthly unemployment rate data dating back to 1990 for every county in the continental US. Each month's unemployment rates are stored in a separate field.

In trying to create an animation, I have only been able to visualize this data in a way that assumes the timestamp is in the attribute, rather than in the field heading.

How can I visualize these data using each attribute field without creating a separate map by hand for every individual month?

[image: This is a screenshot of the attribute table from the file geodatabase I hope to visualize]

Answer (score 2):

It's been a little while since I dealt with time-aware data in ArcGIS but I don't think it's capable of handling time-series data when the different time periods are stored that way, with each time period as a separate attribute of one feature. Instead, you will need one feature per county, per time period. ArcGIS time animations require a start and end time for each feature, so your feature class' attribute table would look something like this:

```
County      Unemployment    DateStart   DateEnd
Monroe      3.4             1/1/2010    1/31/2010
Monroe      3.5             2/1/2010    2/28/2010
Monroe      3.8             3/1/2010    3/31/2010
Logan       4.2             1/1/2010    1/31/2010
Logan       4.5             2/1/2010    2/28/2010
Logan       4.4             3/1/2010    3/31/2010
```

Then when you use those features in a time animation, each row will only be visible between its start and end dates.

If you just need to export a set of maps, each one using a different field for the symbology, you can do that with Python using the `arcpy.mapping` module by looping through each of your time period fields and changing the `valueField` property on the symbology class each time. See these questions for more on that:

[How do I change graduated color class values with python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/111381/how-do-i-change-graduated-color-class-values-with-python/135907#135907)

[Accessing "valueField" property of layer's symbology using ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136804/accessing-valuefield-property-of-layers-symbology-using-arcpy)

And ESRI's help on changing the symbology using `arcpy.mapping`:

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/GraduatedColorsSymbology/00s30000005z000000/

Comment: If the entire attribute table were reformatted in this way, the file would be extremely large and dramatically decrease processing speed. 

Is there a way to produce maps of each attribute field without manually changing the symbology each time?

Comment: @MarieHoller That would be possible using arcpy, if you are not interested in producing an animation and only need a set of maps. But for a time animation, ArcGIS only supports time values in two ways: either a single time field or two fields: a start time and an end time.